# CSS Display Flex in IE 11 not working, images go over

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am using CSS `display: flex;` to display them a certain way. In Chrome it looks perfect, like beautiful, but in IE the images go outside the element I have them in.

https://jsfiddle.net/m42k7Lk5/8/

```css
.award-logos {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  box-align: center;
  align-items: center
}

.award-logos .wrapper {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 10px 17px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px dotted #000
}

.wrapper img {
  max-height: 150px
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 award-logos">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg">
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Flexible layout is [supported with bugs](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex) on IE 11.

Comment: Oh man, that sucks.....there is no way to fix this?

Comment: Try `display: table-cell`.

Comment: Dude, i just opened your fiddle in IE 11, and it worked just the way it did in Chrome.

Comment: Just updated my question with actual Images

Comment: huh even when I run my snippet, it goes over...

Comment: actually the issue still remains, in my js fiddle.

Comment: @doutriforce I tried that, didnt work, it doesnt align everything to the left, the  go underneither each other

Comment: @user979331 I can confirm that the Stack Snippet and the JSFiddle both act the same in Chrome and in IE11 for me.

Comment: Use flex-shrink: 0 on image, example- div > img{flex-shrink: 0; max-width: 100%}
Its working perfectly in IE 11.