# CSS 5 images aligned left with 100% height border

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 5 images and I want them to float left and stay on one line without images being moved to the next line, I also want a border right of 100% I have successfully done this with display: flex, however flex does't work properly in IE 11

Here is my HTML

```
<div class="col-md-12 award-logos">
                    <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg"  />
                    </div>
                     <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg"  />
                    </div>
                     <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg"  />
                    </div>
                     <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg"  />
                    </div>
                     <div class="wrapper">
                        <img src="https://www.hsjaa.com/images/joomlart/demo/default.jpg"  />
                    </div>

                </div>
```

And the CSS

```
.award-logos { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

.award-logos .wrapper {padding: 10px 30px;margin:5px 0;text-align:center;border-right:1px dotted #000; float: left;}

.wrapper img {max-height:150px; padding;}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5sw538t7/

Comment: plunkr plz, thx

Comment: Don't use Plunkr, use Stack Snippet first, then JSFiddle or CodePen. Also, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443890/css-display-flex-in-ie-11-not-working-images-go-over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443890/css-display-flex-in-ie-11-not-working-images-go-over).

Comment: you could use `inline-block` and `white-space: nowrap` instead, will this work? https://jsfiddle.net/5sw538t7/1/

Comment: and assuming I understand the end goal, `flex` on the parent works fine in ie11 https://jsfiddle.net/5sw538t7/2/

Comment: @MichaelCoker inline-block does work, but I upated your fiddle and the border I have around the award-logos does not contain the images https://jsfiddle.net/5sw538t7/3/

Comment: @user979331 if that's a requirement for solving the question, why don't you have that in the post?

Comment: I forgot it. It was in a differnt css block of code

Comment: add `.award-logos { float: left; }` - from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22301513/expand-body-element-width-beyond-width-of-window

Comment: @MichaelCoker I did that, its kinda works in Chrome, my images are contained, in IE they are massive and dont fit

Comment: looks fine to me http://i.imgur.com/PEXFSdQ.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Display Flex in IE 11 not working, images go over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44443890/css-display-flex-in-ie-11-not-working-images-go-over)